# How to prevent "parameter PLSQL_DEBUG is deprecated" compiler warning in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle11g

When I execute a package body DDL statement SQL Developer warns,

```
Warning: PLW-06015: parameter PLSQL_DEBUG is deprecated; use PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL=1
```

How can SQL Developer be configured to not use PLSQL_DEBUG?

PLSQL_DEBUG is set to false in an sql*plus session using the same connection details,

```
> show parameters plsql

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
plsql_ccflags                        string
plsql_code_type                      string      INTERPRETED
plsql_debug                          boolean     FALSE
plsql_native_library_dir             string
plsql_native_library_subdir_count    integer     0
plsql_optimize_level                 integer     2
plsql_v2_compatibility               boolean     FALSE
plsql_warnings                       string      ENABLE:ALL
```

Oracle SQL Developer v 2.1.1.64

Oracle 11g SE: 11.1.0.6.0

I am looking for a GUI option not a login trigger to achieve this.

I am not looking for a way to simply suppress the display of this warning. The warning must not be generated at all.

Comment: Also posted at http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4367551

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to disable a single warning you can use PLSQL_WARNINGS. The oracle documentation for 11g can be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams186.htm)

To disable the warning for your session the usage is:

`ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_WARNINGS='ENABLE:ALL','DISABLE:06015';`

However this will only disable for your current session. If you wanted it to be disabled whenever you login, you would need to add it to your login.sql file used with SQL Developer.

Alternatively I believe you can turn all PL/SQL compiler warnings off in SQL Developer (although i would not recommend this)
Preferences->Database->PL/SQL Compiler Options

It may be possible to remove the plsql_debug parameter, but I am unsure how to do this. Maybe someone else can help here.

Comment: I tried ALL: DISABLE on the compiler options panel but this did not suppress the warning. As you note what I really what is for plsql_debug not to be used. Setting Optimization Level to 1 failed to suppress the warning.

Comment: Executing 'ALTER SESSION set plsql_debug=false' has stopped the warning but sql developer should not be setting this to true to begin with.

Comment: Old thread I know, but I just hit this today. Aside from SQL Developer preference settings, I think the warning text is misleading, as it appears regardless of your session/system settings for `plsql_debug` and `plsql_optimize_level`, whenever any PL/SQL unit is compiled for debug. It will say the same thing whatever you set them to. All it is really saying is that compiling in debug mode has reduced the compiler optimize level to 1.